# select value from another table - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables "srot_data" and "vada"

```
CREATE TABLE `vada`
  (
     `id`    INT(10) NOT NULL,
     `cislo` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `popis` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
  )
engine=innodb
DEFAULT charset=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `srot_data`
   (
     `id`   INT(10) NOT NULL,
     `vada` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL
   );

INSERT INTO `srot_data` (`ID`, `Datum`, `ID_obsluha`, `Linka`, `Kontejner`, `Vada`, `m_srot`, `m_pres`, `blok`) VALUES (1, '2018-04-16 11:23:44', 21, 'EXMET2', 'ELDY-', 18, '27.500', '12.500', 1),(2, '2018-04-16 12:18:06', 21, 'EXMET2', 'ELDY-', 5, '1.000', '0.000', NULL);

INSERT INTO `vada` (`ID`, `Cislo`, `Popis`) VALUES(1, 1, 'Najíždění výroby(resp. nové elektrody)'),(2, 2, 'Expander - poškozená mřížka'),(3, 3, 'Olověný pás - koroze '),(4, 4, 'Olověný pás - potrhaná mřížka'),(5, 5, 'Pastovačka - nedopastované elektrody');
```

Vada from srot_data = ID from vada. And I need to get Popis from table vada.

My sql is:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(blok) AS Total , 
               Vada AS vada 
        FROM srot_data 
        LEFT JOIN vada ON vada.Popis = srot_data.Vada 
        WHERE Linka = 'EXMET1' 
        GROUP BY vada 
        ORDER BY Total DESC limit 1";
```

but it doesn´t work. I'm getting a number (vada from table srot_data). But not getting a text value from Popis (from table vada).

```
{"Total":"37", "vada":"5".}
```

And I need

```
    {"Total":"37", "vada":"Pastovačka - nedopastované elektrody".}
```

Linka and blok are not important for this problem, so I deleted it from tabel for this time.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what, more specifically? Do you get an error or no data or what?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Please, complete the tables schema, there are columns like: `Linka` and `blok` that are referenced on your query, but don't exists on the schema you are showing.

Comment: Hi Supply some sample data with an insert statement, the value you get with your query and the value you would expect.  We would have to guess at the issue without this information

Comment: @EoinS sample data's there. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Mureinik I have been corrected my question. Sorry I'm a beginner.